# how to fix this error cmdline.cpp:93:1: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'option_type' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, netbeans

```
static struct type_fmt formats[ ] = {

{CMDLINE_I, "%i%s"},   /* the trailing "%s" is used for error check */    
{CMDLINE_D, "%d%s"},    
{CMDLINE_X, "%x%s"},    
{CMDLINE_O, "%o%s"},
{CMDLINE_F, "%f%s"},
{CMDLINE_P, "%p%s"},
{0, NULL}  /* If we get here, it's CMDLINE_S: no sscanf buf strcpy() */
};
```

Trying to fix this error for this and have no idea what to do. the error is  error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'option_type' [-fpermissive].

Comment: It's probably your last one. I'm guessing `option_type` is an `enum`. You're trying to convert `0` to an `enum option_type`. `int` is not an `enum`, so the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

As is suggested in the comment, use appropriate type in stead of "0" for the last element.

In the code itself, it seems to suggest CMDLINE_S - why don't you verify what it maps to?